# passing argument ... makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: objective-c, casting

How can I solve this problem?

code:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[buttonStatsInSection objectAtIndex:row]]
```

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'numberWithInteger:' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numberWithInteger:` needs you to give it an `int` to create the `NSNumber`. You are giving it an object, because `objectAtIndex:` returns an object.

Even if the object you have at that row is an `NSNumber`, or anything else, you still need to get an actual `int` data type out of it somehow.

For example, if the object you get back is an `NSNumber`, you could have something like this in the end:

```
NSNumber * myNSNum = [buttonStatsInSection objectAtIndex:row];
int myInt = [myNSNum intValue];
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myInt];
```

Comment: Will you tell me how, please?

Comment: @Stan Pak: What type of object is being returned from `objectItIndex:`?

Comment: @Chris Cooper: Then is it ok that ignore it?

Comment: @Stan Pak: No, look at the edit I made in my answer. The example should be what you are looking for now.

Comment: But if it's already a number so just copy it into your variable.

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[(NSNumber *)[buttonStatsInSection objectAtIndex:row] intValue]];

Comment: Thanks @Chris Cooper. Your answer was helped.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a new NSNumber object? Do you really want a copy of it, or do you just want a reference to it? What do you plan to do with it? If you want a copy, you can just do:

```
NSNumber* copy = (NSNumber*)[[buttonStatsInSection objextAtIndex:row] copy];
```

Otherwise just do:

```
NSNumber* num = (NSNumber*)[buttonStatsInSection objextAtIndex:row];
```

Either way it isn't necessary to go through the process of extracting the int value and the converting it right back to an NSNumber